# how to divide my asp.net web page into 2 webpages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, division

I am writing a webPage using asp.net and c#.

I want to divide my webpage into 2 columns such as in one I will have buttons that change the view in the other column, without "stepping on" the content of the first column.
example:

button 1     |       :) a picture...
button 2     |

I tried to use divisions but I think I'm not using them properly.
any help would be great!
thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Or code the divs like so:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    button 1
    button 2
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    a picture
  </div>
</div>
```

Then the css is:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
} 

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 600px;
}
```

You can change the widths to whatever you want, just make sure that .left width + .right width isn't greater than .wrapper width.  Also make sure that the content of the columns doesn't make them wider (i.e. if your picture is wider than 600px, it'll also break the layout).

Answer (score 0):

You might try posting a bit of code so that we can see what is going on. It sounds like a css problem which is more general than asp.net and c#.

Answer (score 0):

if you divide your page to two web page then you use frame in javascript 
for it's refrence go to www.w3schools.com

Answer (score -2):

You want a table :)

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>button 1</td>
 <td>a picture</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>button 2</td>
 <td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The table haters have come out in force.